# Limit Ionic to only smartphone devices on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

When creating an app with Ionic for iOS, you can easily select on Xcode if the app should be available for iPhone, Ipad or both.

Is there also a possibility to do something similar on Android, Like making the app available only for certain screen sizes?

I am using Ionic and Angular, latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your `manifest` from [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html):

```xml
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]
            android:screenDensity=["ldpi" | "mdpi" | "hdpi" | "xhdpi"
                                   | "280" | "360" | "420" | "480" | "560" ] />
    ...
</compatible-screens>
```